# sending multiple parametrs from asp pages to single php page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

im traing to send multipel parameters from diferent asp pages to single php pages using htaccess but the code dont redirect me to the php page what is wrong ?

```
RewriteEngine On

## 301 Redirects
# 301 Redirect 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Paper/printArticle\.asp$ /redirect-url-301.php? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# 301 Redirect 2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^idr=1&idrs=2&id=3$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Paper/Article\.asp$ /redirect-url-301.php? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# 301 Redirect 3
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^idr=1&id=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^News/Article\.asp$ /redirect-url-301.php? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: What URL are you entering in your browser and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: the url is:localhost/Paper/printArticle.asp?id=14 and the htaccess in in the root of www with the file redirect-url-301.php

Comment: i want from the htaccess to hundel all ids how to do it plz :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need this single redirect rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

## 301 Redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=\d+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Paper/printArticle\.asp$ /redirect-url-301.php? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: and for the tow other url left what to do ?

Comment: if you look closly there 3 url tips to trait that rederect to the same file and send theres parameters to him the urls:#  /Paper/printArticle.asp?id=188624
# /Paper/Article.asp?idr=7&idrs=7&id=189747
#/News/Article.asp?idr=17&id=159999 nest the url to send :redirect-url-301.php

Comment: ok thanks but if you can give me you facebook or somthing i didnt understand fully your code if you can spear 5 min of your time :p

Comment: i coudnt send you long message ^^" but if you can aswer me here if you look closly i have 3 different url withe different numbre of parametrs ho to do it whit your code if you may answer plz ?

Comment: All 3 of your URLs have `id=` parameter and my rule's condition `%{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=\d+` will satisfy all of those URLs.

Comment: mr.anubhava beside id there is idr and idrs what to do about theme :p

Comment: Not getting you question now. Your aim to redirect all those URLs to `/redirect-url-301.php` eventually right?

Comment: yes but if you see ther first url send just id the second send id,idr and idrs and the last send idr and id

Comment: Yes but ALL of them have `id=`

Comment: not just the parameter id they have id plus idr and idrs ^^" if you have facebook or somthing to discus this in just 5 min of your time my problem will be gon ^^"

Comment: i hoop that you will anderstand the probelem i send i message in facebook